# Oracle fetching data from a table and use it to fetch data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables in Oracle DB and one table contains Column A, B and other table contains columns A, B, C. first two columns are same in both the tables, However, columns A, B in both tables have different data so A -> B relationship both tables is different.

So I want to run a query to fetch data which contains Table1 A, Table1 B, Table2C where Table1 B= Table2 B;

```
Select Tab1.A, Tab1.B, (select Tab2.C from Tab2 where  Tab1.B=Tab2.B )
FROM Tab1 WHERE Tab1.A IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your query?  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: With my query third column result is showing up as null instead of picking the value from the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is likely to return an error because there are probably multiple rows in the second table with the same `B` value.  Why not just use `JOIN`?

```
SELECT Tab1.A, Tab1.B, Tab2.C
FROM Tab1 JOIN
     Tab2 
     ON Tab1.B = Tab2.B 
WHERE Tab1.A IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```